# How to apply a slice to a back-end generated data?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Here are my 2 datas in a `<div>`:

```
<div class="NP" id="sliced">{{app.user.Firstname}}{{app.user.Lastname}}</div>
```

I would like to slice these 2 datas so it displays the first letters of each string, in the `div`.

Roughly, I would like to make some like:

```
 {{app.user.Firstname.slice(0,2)}}{{app.user.Lastname.slice(0,2)}}
```

but I don't know how to implement JS or JQUERY into these things.
I tried to attribute a script to the data, in vain

```
 {{ app.user.firstName, {'label_attr' : {'script' : `$("#sliced").slice(0,2);`} }}
```

It returns me a punctuation error even if I only try to attr a simple class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use JS. You just need to use the correct filter. You don't use `.` to access filters, you use the pipe (`|`).

```
<div>{{ app.user.Firstname|slice(0,2) }}{{ app.user.Lastname|slice(0,2) }}</div>
```

Which can also be expressed like this.

```
<div>{{ app.user.Firstname[:2] }}{{ app.user.Lastname[:2] }}</div>
```

[Docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html).